# Auto-generated navigational menu for single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to create an auto-generated navigational menu for a single page website.

```
<!-- html -->
<section id="home">
</section>
<section id="aboutus">
</section>
<section id="contactus">
</section>
<nav id="nav_menu">
</nav>

// jQuery
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('section').each(function(index) {
      $('#nav_menu').append('<a href="'+$(this).hash+'">&diams;<br /></a>')
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'd like to create a diamond for each section in the page, where each diamond will have an anchor to the corresponding page.

The problem is $(this).location.hash shows *undefined* instead of the anchor of the page. I'm not sure about what should I use in order to get the hash of the section.

Comment: `this` refers to the dom element not to `window` in that context, plus `hash` is a property of `location` which is a property of `window`.

Comment: will u clear more?  write your `desired section`

Comment: what do you want at "$(this).location.hash" Do you want a hash over there

Comment: I want the hash (id) of the section over there

Comment: You'll need to do `$(this)[0].id` or `$(this).attr('id')`.  But judging by the functionality you're trying to achieve, you'll need to use `<a name='sectionName'>` tags instead.

Comment: @elclanrs let's say the dom element is section#home, how do I get the id? Using $(this).attr('id')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting the ID of the section

```
$('section').each(function(index) {
  $('#nav_menu').append('<a href="#'+this.id+'">&diams;<br /></a>')
});
```